# ClassCastException: org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.returns.CollectionReturnImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.loader.plan.spi.Fetch

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, formula, classcastexception

I can not define what is wrong with my code. Last time I used it and it wordked, but now when I am trying to read `User`, I get ClassCast execption: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.returns.CollectionReturnImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.loader.plan.spi.Fetch`

I am using Spring Boot and Hibernate, could you help to determine the reason.
User object contains java.util.List of RoleEntity, which contains User in it.

Problem is in the second `@Formula`, first works, I don`t know what is wrong here.

```
@Formula("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rdb.review r WHERE r.entity_id = 
id)")
private Integer reviewsAmount;

@Formula("(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT author_id) FROM rdb.review r WHERE 
r.entity_id = id)")
private Integer peopleEnvolved;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is easy - I need to use `r.author_id` in second formula. But it works fine in MySQL Workbench, but does not work in `@Formula`